# SSIS 2008: Event handler OnError doesn't fire

Tags: ssis, onerror

I can't understand why my OnError event doesn't fire. 
I created a package just for testing purposes, created one Data Flow task, 
set its ForceExecutionResult to Failure so it would trigger an error,
and put a simple sql task in OnError event. 
When i execute the package the Onerror event doesn't get reached. 
DisableEventHandlers is set to false.
Also, when i put the same task in OnPostExecute event it does fire.
Any ideas?

Comment: Setting the ForceExecutionResult to Failure will cause the OnTaskFailed event to execute, not the OnError.

Comment: I was relying on a post by someone explaining how to send error description using send mail task, that's exactly what he did.. But please tell me, does it matter if i execute just one task or the whole package?

Comment: You will need to execute the whole package. According to the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms140223.aspx), "Only the package has an event handler, for its OnError event."

Comment: Ok, thank you. I guess i hurried a little bit with the question, i just couldn't figure it out and needed this urgently..